# Tool that logs the last ~20 keys (and key combinations) I pressed

Tags: linux, open-source, keylogger

When I use the keyboard for certain Firefox functions, and when I do it fast, time and time again something unintentional happens. When I try to do it slowly, everything’s fine. So there must be some timing issue, or an additional key I press, without me noticing it.

Is there a tool which logs the last 20 (or so) keys I pressed? It also has to show which keys were hold down and before which key press they were released.

As soon as it happens again, I’ll stop typing and check the log to learn which keys I pressed in which order.

It has to be a **free/libre** tool for **GNU/Linux**.

Answer (score 2):

You can log all X11 keystrokes with various tools of which `xinput` is the one you probably already have installed. Run xinput to find the id of the keyboard, eg for me it was 3:

```
$ xinput
...
 Virtual core keyboard        id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
```

the use

```
$ xinput --test-xi2 --root 3 >file
```

to record all keystrokes. Example output

```
EVENT type 13 (RawKeyPress)
    device: 3 (9)
    detail: 40
    valuators:
```

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129171/119298) for a script to convert the output keycodes into something more readable.

Another tool is `cnee` part of `Xnee`. Use it with

```
$ cnee --record --keyboard
```

It also just prints raw keycodes. eg

```
6,2,0,0,0,105,0,1551948221,3,Virtual core keyboard
```